# How to install Ralink MT7601U drivers on Ubuntu 20.04 Kernel# 5.4.0-42?

Tags: drivers

Whenever I tried installing through terminal, It shows the below error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/snykyash/Drivers/mt7601usta/src/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:147: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:9: scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c] Error 127
make[2]: *** [Makefile:594: syncconfig] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:704: include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:419: LINUX] Error 2
```

Please help me regarding this issue.